# Vertical-align should be applied to the children?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser, vertical-alignment

Does this property should also affect the children of the element it is applied to ?

[Here is my example](http://jsfiddle.net/5XMk8/4/)

```
span{
 vertical-align:top;
 font-size:27px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
a{
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
}

<span>
  <a>Hi ho hoh ho</a>
  Hi ho hoh ho
  <a>Hi ho hoh ho</a>
</span>
```

On Firefox the property doesn't affect the children but on Chrome the children are misaligned.

Chrome :[image: Chrome]

Firefox : [image: Firefox]

What is the good implementation ?

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/5XMk8/7/

add all text in "a" tag and give `float:left` and make it `display:block`

Comment: this is not dirty trick as "a" tag is not bydefault block so hover will work on the block or you can use float as well

Answer (score 0):

By the specifications, `vertical-align` is not inherited, but it may affect the baseline level of inner elements. Browsers have a long history of quirky and different implementations of this property, though.

Testing with your exact code, I see on Chrome (22beta) just the same as on Firefox, so maybe you have encountered an oddity in some older version.

To see noticeable differences between browsers, use varying font sizes. The results will be harder to interpret. Anyway, the morale is that we should avoid playing with `vertical-align` in most cases. Using relative positioning tends to produce more consistent results.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm using chrome 22 and Firefox 15.

Comment: Current release version of Chrome is 21. If you get the result shown in the screenshot on Chrome 22beta, then this might be an installation issue, or font rendering issue that might depend on device or settings. Your jdsfiddle does not exhibit the issue on my Chrome 22.0.1229.56 beta-m (Win 7).

Comment: You are right I just tried on an other computer and the issue doesn't appear. I will try to re-install Chrome